# Shadows for games

Tags: game-engine, light, shaders

So I don't really know if this was asked before, but I sure couldn't find it, so at least this’ll make a real nice link straight to the right answer.

I have a pretty simple scene, and right now it looks like crap 'cause I'm not real great at lighting. I was watching a tutorial on the game engine (completely unrelated to my problem) and I noticed that the guy who was making the tutorial had shadows in his game, like full-on-dynamic-wicked-cool-looking-shadows. They didn't seem to be stressing his PC or anything so I thought "hey that's cool" and I tried to make them.

In a book by Mike Pan I saw that only spot-lamps and sun lamps give shadows in the game engine so I switch my Hemi out for a sun and *Surprise!* it looks worse.

[image]

My question after that fantastic monologue: How do I get pretty little shadows to make my game look awesome without weirdo lines streaking through it and messing it up?

Comment: You might try setting the type to *variance*. I've often had better results with variance maps.

Comment: Aww. A cute little monkey head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had better luck with the *variance* shadow buffer type:

[image]

[image]

*Just from looking at your file I'm not exactly sure what is "wrong". I don't see any artifacts in the shadow itself (perhaps if you added a screenshot showing exactly what you are referring to with "weirdo lines streaking through it"?).*

Comment: It actually only happens on my linux, so I still need to get a screen capture program. :) thanks, I'll try thsi.

Comment: The quality on yours looks a lot less choppy than mine. did you set any other stuff up?

Comment: @ARadish I added a second lamp so that the shadows weren't completely black, but other than that just some mist and material tweaks. Feel free to poke around in the .blend ;)

Comment: How is that any different from this? http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20869986#20869986

Comment: well my friendly doppelgänger, it isn't. but i asked here because i had a sudden identity crisis and felt it would be better if i got an answer that wasn't from myself.